# How to use Integer in freemarker template?

Tags: spring, struts, long-integer, freemarker

Yesterday, when I attempted to get a variable value from action,
if I set the  variable's which defined in ftl value up to below ten , the result always got empty.

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" id=orderId" value="9" /> 

public class OrderVo {
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return  this.id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}

System.out.println("=============================" +vo.getOrderId());

the result was ""
```

---

Thank you at first,but it doesn't work.
I got it the day before yesterday!
Because for the release of the tomcat.
You may come across problem in the tomcat 6.x,but not 5.x.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Is the missing quote a typo? Are you saying you *enter* 10, or set the value to 10 in the action and want it to appear in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following section in the freemarker manual.

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_number.html

Cheers.